# Background filler issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code should do the following:
A background big semi-black bar that is rotated 5 degrees. 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrb1fcka/)

```
<div class="con-fluid"><div class="_978y"></div></div>

.con-fluid{
  width: 100%;
}
._978y{
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    width: 200%;
    height: 296px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5.13deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5.13deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5.13deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5.13deg);
    transform: rotate(5.13deg);
    }
```

/*as you can see, the rotation code is universal to make sure it works on almost all browsers/
The issue: it's not filling on both its ends. You can see it clearly in the code preview.

what I want is basically filling this empty area so it doesn't look off the chart. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query is not clear. What do you mean by filling? Filling which empty area?

Comment: In the JSFiddle, right:left http://prntscr.com/aoose8.. this is the empty area that I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your query, however, I think you are asking about the missing "triangle" on the top right of the rectangle. It is there because you rotated the rectangle.

To hide it, put `margin-top: -10px;` within the css for `._978y`, moving the rectangle up `10px`.

Comment: In the JSFiddle, right:left http://prntscr.com/aoose8.. this is the empty area that I'm talking about and the margin-top has nothing to do tho. I want to fill this empty area with the same rotation. so it appears like this http://prntscr.com/aoosoq

Comment: Then perhaps transform it to the left by 10px?

Comment: why would I transform it to the left by 10px? if I did so, the other end will appear cut again. I just want it to appear correctly, like if its width is bigger by 105% or so and then centerize it. but unfortunately, if I have an absolute position for such div, it will still show the scroll bar. even after the overflow hidden thing, the content itself will get pushed by the amount of width specified in the class and therefore, the responsiveness will corrupt. Can you give me just an accurate answer regarding this?